# walk around on a terrain (landscape)

Tags: camera, navigation

---

Is there a way to limit the camera to a landscape, when i use gravity activated, for my walk around navigation, because when the camera comes outside, it fall, because of gravity

---

Comment: did you try limit location constraint?

Comment: @Chris Gives an error: "Cannot navigate an object with constraints". Unfortunately locking the height at a certain Z value also doesn't work, in this case the camera "falls" in X and Y direction further away and you can no longer move in the opposite direction.

Comment: I try with a cube to limit location and i try limit distance, but i have to understand the way it work. For the moment i put a plane below my landscape, more larger and i define it with 'Rigid Body' in passive mode, so my camera fall less than before.